# How to correctly assign axios response to react function component state

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-functional-component

I have problem as in title.
My code give me an infinite loop - the console log is looping all time.

I just want to assign axios response to component state nad render elements via .map()

component:

```
const Translator = () => {
    const [languages, setLanguages] = useState([]);
    getLanguages().then(data => {
       setLanguages(data.languages)
    });
    
    console.log(languages);
  
  return (
    <header className="translator__header">
        {languages.map( lang => {
            <h1>{lang.language}</h1>
        })}
    </header>
  );
};
```

resource:

```
export default () => {
    return Axios.get(`${config.baseURL}/languages`, {headers: config.headers}).then(res => {
        return res.data.data;
    });
}
```

request give array with object like this

```
{language: "af"}
```

Comment: Please read up on useEffect.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
Same situation

Comment: What is? Give a [mre].

Comment: Look answer made by @Dyarlen my code now looking like this, but have another problem right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the axios request inside the `useEffect` hook, in order to run once the component is mounted.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Translator = () => {
    const [languages, setLanguages] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      getLanguages().then(data => {
         setLanguages(data.languages)
      });

      console.log(languages);
    }, []);
    
  
  return (
    <header className="translator__header">
        {
          languages.length > 0 && (
            languages.map( lang => <h1>{lang.language}</h1>)
          )
        }
    </header>
  );
};
```

Comment: I put this into useEffect and still working in the same way :/

Comment: Sorry @programmer I forgot to pass an empty array as a second argument. Try it and tell me if it works

Comment: works, but now elements are not rendering. I think there is problem cuz map() creating element when the array it still empty. But i'm not sure ot this

Comment: i put log inside map() and everything is right - objects shows in console, but still not rendered into DOM

Comment: @programmer I edited the code with a conditional if the length is grater than 1 then, it render the h1

Comment: Okay, nobody saw that I didnt put the return state to map() LOL. Sorry for my fault

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you the infinite loop, because you're changing state on each render.
Put this code in `useEffect` hook

```
getLanguages().then(data => {
   setLanguages(data.languages)
});
```

Comment: Nothing happend :/

Comment: Look answer made by @Dyarlen - my code looking like this

Comment: This should work well, because the deps array is empty, to it should run only once. You're still getting infinite console.logs?

Comment: look comments in @Dyarlen answer - there I explain what problem is now

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the useEffect hook.
Passing [] as the second argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount mental model.

> In React, when you use lists, each list item needs a unique key.

```js
const Translator = () => {
    const [languages, setLanguages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getLanguages().then(data => {
           setLanguages(data.languages)
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(languages);
  
    return (
        <header className="translator__header">
            {languages.map(lang => {
                <h1 key={lang.language}>
                    {lang.language}
                </h1>
            })}
        </header>
    );
};
```

Comment: with useEffect like u - looping stop.
I added a key, and now element are not showing

Comment: I thing the map() is creating elements before set data to state, but how can I figure out this?

Comment: @programmer What is the content of the `language`? Does every `language` property have a unique value?